# Responsive canvas: offset not working - FabricJS

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries, fabricjs

I insert `@media screen` in the css for working the responsive design. 
Responsive design is working, but I can not correctly drag, resize and rotate objects

I try insert:

```
canvas.on('after:render', function(){ this.calcOffset(); });
```

or

```
renderAll();
canvas.calcOffset();
```

See

https://jsfiddle.net/qj3oyzs8/

So this not working properly

You can better understand the problem when drawing with the brush. When rendered lines appear in a different location from where it was designed.

In each screen resolution line is drawn in a different location

https://jsfiddle.net/8e69zuym/

So it is not possible to be able to use the resize, drag and rotate properly

I am using [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/)

If I withdraw the `@media screen` the drag, resize and rotate fabricjs work properly. But I need the canvas is responsive.

---

**EDIT**

I found this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874844/fabricjs-objects-not-relative-to-canvas-resize?answertab=active#tab-top) but did not understand how to apply the solution

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running renderAll after calcOffset?